# How to make certain values in dictionary add up to 100?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary with varying number of items. Each item can have a value of either a `1` or `0`. Those with a value of `1` are stored in a list and counted. This is then used to calculate a percentage which would then be used to replace the value `1`.

For example: if I have 10 items and only 7 contain a value of `1`, the calculated percentage would be `100 / 7 = 14`. Therefore those 7 items will have a new value of `14`.

But there is a remainder left over and what I would like is for some items to gain this remainder (so 5 items would have a value of `14`, 2 items would have a value of `15` so that `(5 * 14) + (2 * 15) = 100`.

How could this be done?

---

This is the code I used which gets the percentage value but I am unsure how to implement the remainder part (*I would like to only show integers in the dictionary*):

```
someDict = {
        'item_01': 0,
        'item_02': 0,
        'item_03': 0,
        'item_04': 1,
        'item_05': 1,
        'item_06': 1,
        'item_07': 1,
        'item_08': 1,
        'item_09': 1,
        'item_010': 1
        }

percentage_list = []
for key, value in someDict.items():
    if value == 1:
        percentage_list.append(value)

percentage_value = int(100) / int(len(percentage_list))
# =98

# Replace all 1's in someDict with percentage value
for key, value in someDict.items():
    if value == 1:
        someDict[key] = percentage_value
```

Comment: Your description calculates percentage incorrectly.

Comment: 7/10*100 would generate the correct percentage

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary in the first place when all the key names are just an enumeration? Use a list.

Comment: @timgeb - The key names shown are just an example, they're not enumerated at all :)

Comment: @Joseph ah, ok :)

Comment: shouldn't the percentage be len(percentage_list)/len(some_dict) * 100?

Comment: Thanks all, yes the `percentage_value` is indeed not a true percentage of what I was looking for. Should probably have used another name =)

Comment: This doesn't apply to the question much but if you are only using `percentage_list` to get the length of it and find the number of values equal to `1`, then you could alternatively just do `num=sum(someDict.values())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for some reason your remainder left over is such that each element may gain more than `1`, just after calculating `percentage_value`:

```
num_divisions = len(percentage_list)

remainder = 100 - percentage_value * num_divisions

# Replace all 1's in someDict with percentage value
for i, key in enumerate(filter(lambda k: someDict[k] == 1, someDict)):
    extra = int(remainder/(num_divisions - i))

    someDict[key] = percentage_value + extra

    remainder -= extra
```

Comment: Thanks, will test this out over the weekend and report back :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use // for int division and % for the remainder:

```
someDict = {
        'item_01': 0,
        'item_02': 0,
        'item_03': 0,
        'item_04': 1,
        'item_05': 1,
        'item_06': 1,
        'item_07': 1,
        'item_08': 1,
        'item_09': 1,
        'item_010': 1
        }

percentage_list = []
for key, value in someDict.items():
    if value == 1:
        percentage_list.append(value)

percentage_value = 100 // len(percentage_list)
remainder_value = 100 % len(percentage_list)

# Replace all 1's in someDict with percentage value
for key, value in someDict.items():
    if value == 1:
        if remainder_value > 0:
            someDict[key] = percentage_value + 1
            remainder_value -= 1
        else:
            someDict[key] = percentage_value

print(someDict)
```

Comment: "You should use // for int division and % for the remainder" <- Or the builtin function `divmod`.

Comment: You are right: percentage_value, remainder_value = divmod(100, len(percentage_list)) also works. I wanted to make it more clear by using the single operators, though.

Comment: Thanks, will test this out over the weekend and report back :)

Comment: Instead of checking if `remainder_value` is greater than `0`, you could instead have `someDict[key] = percentage_value + (remainder_value > 0); remainder_value -= 1` and get rid of the if-statement altogether, which I've timed and it runs at the same speed.